# Write a test to ensure Perl script loads a particular module

Tags: perl, testing

I'm writing a testing script using CPAN's [`Test`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test) module. I'd like the script to test to see if my program loads the URI::URL package. Is this possible?

Comment: Test::More has [`use_ok`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Test::More#Module-tests) and `require_ok`...is there any particular reason you're using Test.pm instead of Test::More? Test::More is pretty standard.

Comment: I am using `Test::More`. I did try those tests but they only seem to see if my test script can load the package. I'd like to test if my target script, run from another file, is loading the package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you want to check whether a piece of code loads a certain module.

You can do that by running the piece of code, then checking [`%INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%INC) afterwards:

```
# run your script (e.g. via 'do' or 'require')
# ...

ok $INC{'URI/URL.pm'}, "URI::URL was loaded";
```

Answer (score 4):

It might be better to use the module `Module::Loaded` instead of parsing `%INC`. It is a core module since perl 5.9.4.

http://perldoc.perl.org/Module/Loaded.html

```
use Module::Loaded;

if (is_loaded('URI::URL')) {
  print "Is loaded\n";
} else {
  print "Is NOT loaded\n";
}
```

Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: This works fine in this context, but beware: In list context, `is_loaded` returns nothing (an empty list) on failure (instead of false). This weird behavior is undocumented and can trip you up: `foo(is_loaded("Weird::Stuff"))` actually calls `foo()` without arguments.

Comment: @zdim It's all fun and games until you do something like `my %hash = (foo => 1, bar => is_loaded($module), baz => 2)` and then `is_loaded` suddenly returns an empty list and your subsequent keys become values and vice versa. And then you have a security hole in your bugzilla or CGI code (see the infamous "Perl Jam" talk). There the culprit was `$cgi->param()`, which is at least documented to return a list!

Comment: @zdim No, if `is_loaded` always returns a scalar (including `undef`), all is fine.

Comment: @melpomene: You will find that a large number of library subroutines do exactly the same thing, because that is what a bare `return` statement does by design. Your example of building a list that includes a subroutine call is not a problem with the module, but a mistake in coding the list. `bar => scalar is_loaded($module)` would be correct. The difference is at the heart of the Perl language, and is far from being *weird behaviour*.

Comment: @Borodin It is a problem with the module because all built-in boolean-result operators always return 1 value. The name `is_loaded` implies the function is a predicate (and so does its documentation). Nothing indicates the function goes out of its way to do a bare `return;` to return "false". Speaking generally, IMHO when you're writing a subroutine, you should decide up front whether it returns exactly one value or a list (multiple values). Playing games with `wantarray` (or bare `return`) should be done very sparingly, because it is so error prone: Most people don't add `scalar` everywhere.

Comment: @Borodin PS: Lots of things in Perl are weird :-). That includes scalar `..` (and `...`), `reset`, hashes in scalar context, `open` using a normal return value *and* an output parameter *and* a global variable to communicate results back to its caller, etc. That doesn't mean you have to use them. (I know Damian Conway recommends `return;` in PBP, but this is one thing I think he got completely backwards.)

Comment: @melpomene: Then I think it's fair to say that you're in the minority and simply don't "get" Perl. Perhaps you shouldn't be answering questions on a language you think is so weird. A lot of it falls into place if you remember that it's structured around  a natural language grammar.

Comment: @Borodin "*Perhaps you shouldn't be answering questions on a language you think is so weird*" - Dude, I know Perl (and (parts of) perl), I like Perl, and I like helping people with Perl. I didn't know that being a fanboy was a requirement, too.

Comment: @melpomene: I just think it detracts from any answers you write if you can't resist making irrelevant comments on the weirdness of the language.

Comment: @melpomene  Design wise, I think that equally good arguments can be made for both.  In a language that allows flat list returns (and uses them liberally) I find it natural to get an empty list for false. As for a function `is_...` I expect a scalar use so I'll be careful if it's in a list context. But if I may want a list back I'd rather have an empty one. I agree that it may get tricky but Perl freely mixes low and high level features so that's not so unusual. I completely agree that module docs should make a clear statement.

Comment: @Borodin My original comment called the semantics of `is_loaded` weird. This has nothing to do with the language.